# How can I access the shared link for a file/folder (sent in an email) through Sharepoint REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, ms-office

I want to get a hold of the link that Sharepoint sends in an email to the person we share an file/folder with, through the REST API.
I'm using Office365 and I am referring to the link under "Open to anyone with a guest link" under Sharepoint/Onedrive section for a file/folder.

When an item(file etc) is shared, I fetch the change logs, and from that I identify which item was shared and with whom.
What I can't find is the shared link! My goal is to somehow access that url, then delete it so that I can unshare that item(Refer to >>> http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-help/manage-sharing-with-external-users-HA102849862.aspx#_Toc336605373). I want to achieve this through REST API.

Is this even possible?